# Wordpress posts, link to category pages

Tags: php, wordpress

Within this wordpress function:

```
function ct_post_nav() { ?>
        <ul>
           <li class="post-nav-all">
              <?php $linktitelposts = get_cat_ID( $cat_name );          
                 if ($linktitelposts == 'blogs' )
                 {$linktitelposts = '<a href="#">Lees alle blogs</a>';}
                 if ($linktitelposts == 'vacatures')
                 {$linktitelposts = '<a href="#">Lees alle vacatures</a>';}
             ?> 
           </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- .nav-links -->
</nav><!-- .navigation -->
```

I want a link back to the categorie pages inside the li. The php lines that are in there now are what I tried, but of course it does not work. Is there a way to get a link that changes per category?

Comment: what are you getting in `var_dump($cat_name)` ? where this `$cat_name` is defined ?

Answer (score 0):

Try  this and `function` ruls is `return` or `echo` value

```
<?php function ct_post_nav($cat_name) { 
            // Get the ID of a given category
            $linktitelposts = get_cat_ID( $cat_name );
            // In this variable `$linktitelposts` Your Category ID and Pass this id
            // Get the URL of this category
            $category_link = get_category_link( $linktitelposts );


        <!-- Print a link to this category -->

            if ($linktitelposts == 'blogs' )
            {
             // Not use Same variable `$linktitelposts` 
             echo $anLink = '<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>">Lees alle blogs</a>';
            }
            else if ($linktitelposts == 'vacatures')
            {
             // Not use Same variable `$linktitelposts` 
             echo  $anLink = '<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>">Lees alle vacatures</a>';
            }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried something like this. But it only linked back to the same post. And if I use your version it crashes the site.

Comment: @bhaveshvala functions requires `$cat_name` arguments so it should be like `function ct_post_nav($cat_name) { `

Comment: I tried your changes, I also changed the href's to the actual pages, on the blog page it works, but on a different page it keeps the same link.

Comment: ok use <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>" target = _blank>